# Multilang Keyword Url

Tags: php, codeigniter

Lately I received a project in CodeIgniter, and all of this is quite new to me. I have a website in multi-language, and the structure of the URL is like:

http://domain.com/properties/...

Basically what I need is the keyword "properties" be changed when I switch to another language, the site content already makes this but is missing the keyword. I been looking about routes and here is the structure of my route:

```
$route['(:any)/properties/(:any)'] = "(:any)/show/detail/$2";
```

And I'm trying to make this:

```
$route['(:any)/lang_key('property_lang')/(:any)'] = "(:any)/show/detail/$2";
```

But I guess I'm not doing the right way, could someone tell me how should I do it?

Comment: Which version of codeigniter are we talking about ?

Comment: the version is 2.0.3

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see is through the db.

Build a table that looks like this :

routes_translation

```
**********************************
*id |  term   | controller | lang*
**********************************
* 1 | home    |    home    | en  *
* 2 | accueil |    home    | fr  *
                ...
**********************************
```

Then in your routes.php

```
require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB'. EXT );
$db =& DB();
$query = $db->get('routes_translation');
$result = $query->result();
foreach( $result as $row )
{
    $route[$row->term] = $row->controller;
}
```